# SQL Server : separate first and last name and remove middle initial into just two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column that has an individuals full name, including the middle initial. I am trying to separate the full name into just first name and last name and eliminating the middle name/initial. Some of the names in my database have a middle name/initial and some don't. The following query's are what I am using and they both do only half the trick.

Query #1: returns the first name and middle name/initial in the 2nd column and eliminates the last name:

```
FirstName = LEFT(fullname, CHARINDEX(' ', fullname)), 
LastName = RIGHT(fullname, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(fullname)))
```

Query #2: returns the first name and combines the middle name/initial with the last name (with a space between the two):

```
FirstName = left(fullname,CHARINDEX(' ',fullname)),
LastName =  SUBSTRING(fullname, CHARINDEX(' ',fullname)+1,LEN(fullname)-(CHARINDEX(' ',fullname)-1))
```

Comment: Keep in mind that you'll run into problems with people whose last names are multiple, like van der Beek or del Rio, etc. You could deal with the common ones as a separate case if you needed, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
select left(fullname, charindex(' ', fullname + ' ') - 1) as firstname,
       right(fullname, charindex(' ', reverse(fullname) + ' ') - 1) as lastname
```

Note this handles names with no spaces without giving an error.  However, the first and last name are the same (the full string).  It is unclear what you want to do in this case.